# Sending post formData with axios doesn't work, but with request does

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, node-request

I am trying to migrate from [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), since request has been deprecated.
Suppose that the url 'https://www.example.com' receives a post request with formdata that contains login information, and prints 'Logged in' on success and 'Could not log in' otherwise(I can't share the url for privacy reasons).
I have the following code, which uses axios and prints 'Could not log in':

```
axios = require('axios')
FormData = require('form-data')
form = new FormData()
form.append('email', 'example@gmail.com')
form.append('password', '1234')
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    data: form
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response['data']); // Prints "Could not log in"
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

I also have the following code, which uses request and prints 'Logged in':

```
request = require('request')
request.post({
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    method: 'POST',
    formData: {
        'email': 'example@gmail.com',
        'password': '1234'
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body); // Prints "Logged in"
})
```

Why does the operation work using request but not axios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the output of the Request code:

```
content-length: 288
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------539399892261259576142530

----------------------------539399892261259576142530
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

example@gmail.com
----------------------------539399892261259576142530
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

1234
----------------------------539399892261259576142530--
```

And here is the output of the Axios code:

```
content-length: 288",
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: "axios/0.19.2

----------------------------076596858609798080293678
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

example@gmail.com
----------------------------076596858609798080293678
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

1234
----------------------------076596858609798080293678--
```

Try adding this option in Axios: `` headers: {'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}` } ``

Comment: Flawless!
How did you print the output?

Comment: I used beeceptor.com to receive the request 

Comment: Could you try helping me with this new question that I posted?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894678/how-can-i-improve-the-elegancy-of-my-code-that-uses-axios