# How can I improve the elegancy of my code that uses axios?

Tags: node.js, axios, node-request

I am trying to migrate from [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), since request has been deprecated.
Suppose that the url 'https://www.example.com' receives a post request with formdata that contains login information, and also suppose that I need to maintain the current session across multiple requests(for that I need a cookieJar). 
Using axios I need cookieJar support from an external library therefor I use [axios-cookiejar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support).
Also to send formdata using axios I have to use the external library [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data), and I also have to set the headers manually since axios doesn't do that for me.
I have the following code, which uses axios that does just that:

```
axios = require('axios')
FormData = require('form-data')
axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default
tough = require('tough-cookie')
axiosCookieJarSupport(axios)
cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar()
form = new FormData()
form.append('email', 'example@gmail.com')
form.append('password', '1234')
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    data: form,
    headers: {'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${form._boundary}` },
    jar: cookieJar,
    withCredentials: true
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response['data'])
})
```

Using request this becomes much simpler:

```
request = require('request')
requestCookieJar = request.jar()
request.post({
    url: 'https://www.example.com',
    method: 'POST',
    jar: requestCookieJar,
    formData: {
        'email': 'example@gmail.com',
        'password': '1234'
    }
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
})
```

As you can see the request API is much more elegant.
Is there a way to use axios more elegantly or is there a different elegant API, which isn't deprecated, that I could use to support my needs stated at the beginning of this question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will be better answered on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can't you use `axios.create()` to create a reusable version of axios that has a bunch of options already preset?

Comment: I'm not using more than one instance of axios here so that won't help

Comment: So, if you're only making this call in one place, what's the question then?  `axios()` is what it is.  If you need a bunch of lines of code to set it up the way you need, then that's what it is, nothing you can do about that.  So, I'm really not sure what you're asking.  The `request()` library just has more features.  If you want to use those features to make your code shorter, then use the `request()` library.

Comment: Came here for the same reason.  Coming from Python requests, working with cookies is easy but axios is a bit more complex